# Finding Term in PV formula with negative interest rate

Tags: python, annuity

I'm trying to replicate BA II Plus precision in finding term (N) in the Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity Formula. Specifically, with negative interest rates (where I can't use natural logarithms). My code is below, but it is both slow, and marginally less accurate. Is there a better way I can do this?

```
# code to find term (n) in present value of annuity formula, where the 
# interest rate is negative, i.e. -55.31257% in below example, as the
# general way to solve, i.e natural logarithms don't work with negative 
# interest rates.

pv = 1559606.4
pp = 100
i = -.5531257
# below is the desired answer
# n = 11.251357

# where interest rate is negative
for num in range(1,100000000):
   expn = num/1000000
   temp3 =  pv - pp*(1 - (1+i)**-expn)/i

   #set level of precision, i.e. accurate to within
   if temp3 <= 0.00000001:
       n = num/1000000
       print("The Number of periods is " + str(n))
       n = float(n)
       break
```

Comment: Have you tried [`numpy.pv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.pv.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`numpy.nper()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nper.html), like:

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np 
np.nper(i, -pp, pv)
```

#### Test Code:

```
pv = 1559606.4
pp = 100
i = -.5531257
# below is the desired answer
# n = 11.251357

import numpy as np

print(np.nper(i, pp, -pv))
```

#### Results:

```
11.2513570023
```